# What is the correct oil change interval between oil changes?

Tags: oil, oil-change, service-intervals

I have a 2010 Dodge Dakota (4.7L V8), 2WD, and approx. 146,200 miles on it. I have maintained it well ever since I purchased it back when it had 106,000 miles on it. Currently, I change the oil and filter every 5,000 miles, using Mobil-1 5W-20 fully synthetic oil designed for engines over 75,000 miles. About 70% of my driving is in town, whereas the other 30% is out on the highways where I can get it up to between 70-80 MPH and do an "[Italian tune-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_tuneup)" (Thanks [Scotty Kilmer](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuxpxCCevIlF-k-K5YU8XPA)), if you will.

Everybody seems to differ on the interval in which they change their oil. I've heard it said that higher-mileage vehicles need it done every 3,000 miles, some do it every 5,000 miles, and others say that it's safe to wait until 7,500 miles if you're using the fully-synthetic good-quality oil (i.e. Mobil-1, Royal Purple).

For the scenario I have described, what is the correct interval in which to change my oil?

Comment: Your best reference here is the Owners Manual.  It will specify the manufacturer's recommended oil change interval.

Comment: Agreed, the manufacturer’s figure is the only one that can be considered ‘correct’, but this is necessarily a ‘one size fits all’ value.  If you consider your driving habits, operating temperatures, use of top quality oil and the balance of longevity vs maintenance costs, you are free to extend or shorten the interval.  Looking at the waste oil when you change it generally gives a good indication; if it looks like it should have been changed earlier then it probably should have.

Comment: Your Dakota doesn't have an oil life meter?

Comment: I used to change oul at 20000 miles but filters every 5000, as oil is expensive and filters cheap but I was using 5W-50…

Comment: There should be one oil change interval between oil changes.